# How can asynchronous microservices communication performs betters in the perspective of UI?

Tags: spring, angular, asynchronous, microservices, event-driven

In my Angular UI, I call an endpoint from API gateway such as:

```
this.http.post(`/order`).subscribe(order => addNewOrderToList(order));
```

According to best practise in microservices, the `/order` handler should publish an event that to be consumed by one or more microservices, instead of calling each other using synchronous REST.  So, I write the following handler:

```
@RequestMapping
public Future<Order> addOrder() {
  CompletableFuture<Order> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
  // publish event
  // ...
  // wait for final event raised by a service.
  future.complete(createdOrder);
  return future;
}
```

From the perspective of the UI, isn't that user will not see the new order until my endpoint returned a new order?  I feel like the UI is still synchronous even when the backend is asynchronous. What is the best practice to improve the UI in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps what you should do is to embrace asyncrony and eventual consistency in this case.

Your HTTP endpoint, when invoked, actually does nothing, it only accepts the UI command, and enqueues it for other backend microservices to eventually process it, right?

So, what you probably should do is just accept the command, validate it, enqueue it and just return a HTTP status code [202 Accepted](https://httpstatuses.com/202) to the client. You could include an ETA header in your response indicating more or less when the client can poll another endpoint to check if the results are ready. If you're following a [truly RESTful approach](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven), you may include the link to the resource the client can use to poll the results when ready.

You may want to read the following articles:

- [REST and long-running jobs](https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/)
- [Eventual consistency in REST APIs](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/05/15/eventual-consistency-in-rest-apis/)
- [4 Ways to Handle Eventual Consistency in the UI](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/27/4-ways-handle-eventual-consistency-ui/)

Comment: The article "4 Ways to Handle Eventual Consistency in the UI" describes my problem.  I finally choose solution 3 in the article: "Fake it".  So, I created new `Order` in Angular as soon as I called backend.  The backend will return information required to create the fake object such as id.  But somehow, I feel unsecure if user interacts with this fake `Order` immediately (it takes several seconds for real `Order` to be saved).  If you could provide more links or patterns about this UI problem, I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Obviously you will only fake it if the backend responds with 202 Accepted, because you may still get 400 or 500 errors from backend, in whose case you should not fake  the order. Something else you could do is that if the user interacts with the order before it is completed in the backend, you could offer limited functionality, e.g. you can see only minor details already known in the front-end, and you let the user know that the rest of the features will be enabled once the orders has been reified in the backend. You may add features to notify the user when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

THere are two ways to do this but both the cases UI/client call the services Asynchronously

1. Implement RestController which can be accessed in Synchronously but Asynchronous nature added from the browser. This is more traditional way
2. Make the Controller method reactive. UI call the service and notified when the data is available. This is new and supported by SPring 5.0

Both are good but #1 approach is old but #2 requires more handle both in UI and server. Adding asynchronous behavior will add better customer experience i.e. they can do other stuff in the UI without waiting for the data.

Comment: Could you add more example for approach #1?  Imagine I'm adding a new "Reply" to comment asynchronously.  I don't want to wait for a response from backend so I immediately create a new dummy "Reply" object and added it into the Angular2 list so that user can see their reply as soon as possible.  This object doesn't have id.  What if user click "Like" on it before the backend is ready?